# Laravel 5.7 - Broadcasting - socket.io - redis : Nothing happen on client

Tags: php, laravel-5, redis, socket.io, laravel-echo

Since few days I read about how to setup laravel-echo on my local machine. I manage to be able to run laravel-echo-server with redis and socket.io.

The problem is that the event is fired, but nothing happen on the client side.

I know that the event is fired, because it's log into my horizon.log file.

```
Horizon started successfully.
[2018-08-29 18:35:30][31] Processing: App\Events\NewModel
[2018-08-29 18:35:31][31] Processed:  App\Events\NewModel
```

Then, into my echo.log file, I can see that the user is connected to the channel and echo trigger the event.

```
L A R A V E L  E C H O  S E R V E R

version 1.3.9

⚠ Starting server in DEV mode...

✔  Running at localhost on port 60010
✔  Channels are ready.
✔  Listening for http events...
✔  Listening for redis events...

Server ready!

[6:35:15 PM] - QW3VITRzWPH4FvxPAAAB joined channel: channel-name
Channel: presence-channel-name
Event: App\Events\NewModel
```

It run on port 60010, because when I tried to do it on port 6001, the client is unable to connect.

I'm using virtualbox/homestead on a windows 10 machine.

There is the port forwarding into my Homestead.yaml

```
ports:
    - send: 60010
      to: 6001
```

So, I don't understand why client don't log the event. There is why my code at the moment

echo.js

```
/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

import Echo from "laravel-echo"
window.io = require('socket.io-client');
// Have this in case you stop running your laravel echo server
if (typeof io !== 'undefined') {
  window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':60010',
  });
    console.log('Connected to socket.io');
} else {
    console.log('Not connected to socket.io');
}

window.Echo.channel('channel-name')
    .listen('NewModel', (e) => {
        console.log('1:');
        console.log(e);
    })
    .listen('App\Events\NewModel', (e) => {
        console.log('2:');
        console.log(e);
    })
    .listen('App.Events.NewModel', (e) => {
        console.log('3:');
        console.log(e);
    });
```

laravel-echo-server.json

```
{
    "authHost": "https://app.torque.homestead",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [{
        "appId": "appId",
        "key": "key"
    }],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "port": "6379",
            "host": "127.0.0.1"
        },
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": "",
    "port": "60010",
    "protocol": "https",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "app.torque.homestead.crt",
    "sslKeyPath": "app.torque.homestead.key",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": "",
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

channels.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Broadcast Channels
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may register all of the event broadcasting channels that your
| application supports. The given channel authorization callbacks are
| used to check if an authenticated user can listen to the channel.
|
*/


Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

Broadcast::channel('channel-name', function () {
    return true;
});
```

If you want to see another file, let me know. Actually I don't know what could be needed to fix the issue.

I think the problem may come from the forwarding port... But like I said, using 6001 is not working.

I tried many things like changing port(maybe not the right combination like client on 60010 and server on 6001????)

I also change that line into echo.js many times

```
host: window.location.hostname + ':60010',
```

There is some version of what i'm using :

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ node -v
v10.8.0
vagrant@homestead:~$ npm -v
6.4.0
vagrant@homestead:~$ php -v
PHP 7.2.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Aug 19 2018 07:16:54) ( NTS )
```

packages.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.1.14",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
        "vue": "^2.5.17"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands": "^5.0.13",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular": "^5.0.13",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid": "^5.0.13",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts": "^1.0.9",
        "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "0.0.22",
        "ajv": "^6.5.3",
        "bootstrap-confirmation2": "^4.0.1",
        "datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
        "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.19",
        "datatables.net-buttons": "^1.5.3",
        "datatables.net-buttons-bs4": "^1.5.3",
        "express": "^4.16.3",
        "ioredis": "^4.0.0",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.4.0",
        "laravel-echo-server": "^1.3.9",
        "socket.io": "^2.1.1",
        "socket.io-client": "^2.1.1",
        "vee-validate": "^2.0.9",
        "vue-inject": "^2.1.1",
        "yarn": "^1.9.4"
    }
}
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "aloha/twilio": "^4.0",
        "eyewitness/eye": "dev-beta",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/horizon": "^1.3",
        "laravel/passport": "^6.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

### Thank you for helping me!

### --EDIT--

After mcklayin suggest me, I look for redis data. So I run this :

```
vagrant@homestead:/var/lib$ redis-cli --scan
presence-channel-name:members
horizon:1
horizon:34
horizon:supervisors
horizon:measured_jobs
horizon:9
horizon:monitor:time-to-clear
horizon:job:App\Jobs\ProcessModels
horizon:35
horizon:queue:default
horizon:job_id
horizon:job:App\Events\NewModel
horizon:masters
horizon:last_snapshot_at
horizon:33
horizon:master:homestead-xVse
horizon:failed_jobs
horizon:32
horizon:supervisor:homestead-xVse:supervisor-1
horizon:recent_jobs
horizon:measured_queues
```

### --EDIT 2--

There is the App\Events\NewModel.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class NewModel implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'NewModel';
    }
}
```

Comment: Did client connect to socket successfully?

Comment: I think... In echo.log i can see this ````[6:35:15 PM] - QW3VITRzWPH4FvxPAAAB joined channel: channel-name````. This come from the my laravel-echo.conf file handle by supervisor.

It's say that the client join the channel and the client console recieve this message ````Connected to socket.io```` from echo.js file.

Comment: What is your QUEUE_DRIVER ? If you use redis,  I think your broadcasts can be in queue

Comment: Both my broadcast and queue are set as redis ````BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis```` ````QUEUE_DRIVER=redis```` --- I just look at my config files and it's set to use the .env variable.

Comment: Look on redis data

Comment: I just add an edit to show the result of redis-cli --scan

Answer (score 0):

Try to add, to the App\Events\NewModel:

```
public function broadcastAs()     
{         
    return 'NewModel';     
}
```

And add the dot symbol before event name on client side:

```
window.Echo.channel('channel-name')
    .listen('.NewModel', (e) => {
        console.log('1:');
        console.log(e);
    })
```

Comment: I just did as you suggest. echo.log and horizon.log show that the event was processed, but nothing happen on client side.

Comment: try to change window.Echo.channel('channel-name') to window.Echo.private('channel-name')

Comment: I just did and change the shouldBroadcastOn() to PrivateChannel('channel-name') into NewModel.php and still the same result.

Comment: Could you please add NewModel.php to question description?

Comment: Take a look at --EDIT 2--